# Ubuntu packages installation is terribly slow

Tags: apt, 20.04, performance

It takes a lot of time for unpacking packages (about 10 sec to 20 sec even for small packages), even after a new installation. I am using a Lenovo Ideapad 330.

I don't know whether it's a hardware problem or a software one.

My Ubuntu specs:

[image: Ubuntu specs]

See [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/1caE3QRbm-M)

Half of the hard disk is empty.

Downloading is done in 15 mins but it takes about 3 to 4 hours for a system update. How can I check what is causing the problem?.

Comment: Please edit your question with the Ubuntu version you are using.  Are you using the terminal to update or an application/program?  What repository are you using?  Also give some specs on your computer. RAM Processor Hard disk.  Check how full your hard disk is.  Ubuntu can run till nearly full but then it can't go as fast.

Comment: Do you get any errors or warnings? Have you checked `top` during an install?

Comment: No, no error. Its always the case.

Comment: What are you trying to install? It could be your internet connection

Comment: Just regular upgrade, no downloading is done in 15 mins, its installation that taking many hours.

Comment: ok, thank you, Could you please post the logs? for apt?

Comment: Run `top` in parallel to the `apt-get` and watch the wait-states (wa), press `1` in top to see the load per CPU. If the wait-states are at a 100% on one CPU, check the `dmesg` output. There are probably some error messages from the hard drive.

Comment: The wait-states are at 100% in many cpu. This is my dmsg log: https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/QmTdKyQ8Dg8AkNtSM7YCaRCh6jecGvhampzKMD2s63c2D6

Comment: Try installing `ioping` and post the output of it running for 30 seconds or so.

Comment: Can you try some network speed rating?

Comment: @AmiyaBehera From the video, it looks like the cause is probably a slow hard drive. In addition to the `ioping` output, post the output of `sudo smartctl --info /dev/sda`.

Comment: Could be due to slow RAM speeds, high CPU usage, slow drive write speeds, slow internet speeds. Check logs, and system speeds for more information on the cause.

Comment: Bunch of things to do. Give it a look to `dmesg`, many of the errors are logged there, not only HDD related (for example thermal problem, disk failures memory errors...). If there is a buggy HDD you will see there something  and even more with the `smartctl` tools. 
Try to clean the cache folders of apt. From the video you posted it seems the cursor stops to promt. Do you remember if it was so or if it is only the video frame rate? Side note:`libreoffice-common`, once opened, is a 54 Mb size for 2709 files. It always slows down the installation.

Answer (score 7):

It's most likely a slow hard drive. To figure out what component in your system is slow you can run hperf
https://github.com/openlvc/hperf
I've used it to find disk bottlenecks on VMWare servers.

When you are running it keep note of what suite causes a noticeable lag in the interface. You can then re-run any individual suites or tests suites to verify that area as the root cause.

Folks were mentioning using top. There are other "better" top like programs. I like htop but there is an even better one called "glances". This will give you a graph of disk/network/cpu IO with colors.
https://github.com/nicolargo/glances

Comment: excellent suggestion ... I really like using  glances  for this kind of troubleshooting

Comment: I formated the system, it's working fine now.